# Making bolded texts never italic

Tags: fonts

Is there a convenient way to make sure that all bolded texts in my document are never italic? Here is a MWP:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    This \textbf{word} is in italic.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    This \emph{\textbf{word}} is not in italic.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In other words, I would like to produce the second outcome using only `\textbf` (and without `\emph`), and apply this effect to the whole document.

**EDIT**: I understand that it may not be the best practice, but I'd like to redefine the `\textbf` command, as I can conveniently invoke it on overleaf using Ctrl + B.

Answer (score 4):

You can re-define the `\textbf` macro:

```
\def\textbf#1{{\upshape\bfseries#1}}
```

Comment: There are at least two important reasons why this should ***not*** be done in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't redefine `\textbf`, but rather define a semantic command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bemph}{\upshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    This \bemph{word} is in italic.
\end{theorem}

This \bemph{word} is not in italic.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* want to redefine `\textbf`, then ***don't*** do `\def\textbf#1{{\upshape\bfseries#1}}` as suggested in another answer: there are several reasons why this is wrong in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\upshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    This \textbf{word} is in italic.
\end{theorem}

This \textbf{word} is not in italic.

\end{document}
```

But I can't recommend doing it.

What are (some of) the reasons? Compare the following two lines

[image]

The top line is with `\bemph` (or `\textbf` redefined as I showed), the bottom line is with the proposed definition. The “naive” redefinition with `\def` doesn't take care of italic corrections fore and aft.

Second reason: `\textbf` should be a robust command, which it isn't if you use `\def`.

Comment: Second reason is irrelevant: `\upshape` is defined by `\protected` and `\bfseries` is defined as `\protect\bfseries `. So, the new `\textbf` macro expands to `{\upshape\bfseries text}` which doesn't mater, Moreover, it shows that LaTeX macros are defined inconsistently.

Comment: @wipet This comment only shows that you didn't bother to understand the *main* reason and to realize that `\textbf` does *much more* than `{\upshape\bfseries text}`, which is why it must be robust. So, contrary to your statement, this also shows greater consistency ensured by `\DeclareTextFontCommand`.

Comment: This comment only shows that you didn't notice that my comment was about the second reason, no about the first reason. And I noticed a new inconsistency in the LaTeX concept. User can declare `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\b}{\upshape\bfseries}` without any warning. So the requirement discussed in another thread "How to get rid of \def" seems to be imperfect because a user can say `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\c}{...}` and the original meaning of `\c` is lost without warning and no `\def` is here.

Comment: @wipet No, you're wrong: `LaTeX Info: Redefining \textbf on input line 4.` is in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the command \textnormal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    \textnormal{This \textbf{word} is in normal.}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    This \emph{\textbf{word}} is not in italic,  \textnormal{but this in normal}.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```